# How to hide br tag which append after every html tag

Tags: html, css

Please provide any relevant solution hide br tag which is append after every html tag,i have tried but not fixed it,when using display none br tag it also append br tag in style,
how to display none br tag not append it any html tag,
writing this html in zoho invoice https://invoice.zoho.in  editor 
here is code:

```
<style>
    <br>div br {
        display: none
    }

    <br>
</style><br><br>
<div style="font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><br> <br><br><br>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF "><br>
                    <div style="padding: 15px; max-width: 600px;margin: 0 auto;display: block; border-radius: 0px;padding: 0px; border: 1px solid lightseagreen;"><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <table style="width: 100%;background: #5d5657 ;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><br>
                                        <div><br> <br><br><br><br>
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;padding:10px;"><br>
                                                            <img style="float:left; " width="111" src="https://wire-itsolutions.com/images/logo.png">
                                                            <br> <br> <span style="color:white;float:right;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic; padding:10px; font-size: 14px; font-weight:normal;"><br>
                                                                <div>Wire-IT Solutions </div><br>
                                                                <div>915 NW 1st Ave Apt H808,</div><br>
                                                                <div>Miami, FL 33136</div><br>
                                                            </span><br> </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table><br>
                                        </div><br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <table style="padding: 10px;font-size:14px; width:100%;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding:10px;font-size:14px; width:100%;"><br>
                                        <p>Hi [FIRSTNAME],</p><br>
                                        <p><br> Your verification code for email verify is [VCODE] . [SITE]. </p><br>
                                        <br>
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p><br>
                                        <p>Thank you regard </p><br> <br> <br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><br>
                                        <div align="center" style="font-size:12px; margin-top:20px; padding:5px; width:100%; background:#eee;"><br>
                                            © 2018 <a href="#" style="color:#333; text-decoration: none;">Wire-IT
                                                Solutions. All Rights Reserved.<br><br> </a><br> </div><br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><small></small></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table><br>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should contact Zoho and tell them that their HTML editor is absolute garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in css file and import that css file into HTML.

```
br {
        display: none
    }
```

I will suggest to use Visual Studio Code as editor it's a free and very good editor.